# Metadata API-based deploys hang in "queued status" since 30.11 (cs7 & cs8 sandbox)

Tags: apex, deployment, ide, sandbox, metadata-api

Is anybody else experiencing this?

Several sandboxes in our Unlimited Edition seem to be having issues with deployments today (tested from Eclipse IDE and Migration Tool). The deploys just hang in the status "Queued" on the "Monitor Deployments" page and request eventually timeouts in Eclipse.

The org itself doesn't seem to be locked because I was able to modify my unit test manually in the GUI.

Production org is on eu1, sandboxes (both developer & full) are on cs7 and cs8. Nothing on trust.salesforce.com & "known issues".

[image: My "Monitor Deployments"]

Comment: It happened to me too once few days back and i had to call salesforce support and they resolved us .Not a bad option to contact premiere support

Comment: @MohithKumar We've filed the case already, waiting now. Did they give you any kind of explanation of the cause or they just waved the magic wand & fixed it ;) We plan to make an important deployment over the weekend so this raises all kinds of alarm bells...

Comment: No they just asked our Org Id and they just did magic .We were told its there issue .

Comment: I've been having save problems since this morning to a cs7 sandbox, not investigated enough yet to figure out what's going on.

Comment: I still seem to be having problems on CS7. Sometimes managing to save from Eclipse, sometimes timing out.

Comment: @eyescream, your deploys working again ? Everything looks to be working fine again on my orgs.

Comment: @Sdry: Just checked. Seems to be indeed OK, was really random throughout the day (for example save of class works, retrieve of `*.object` timeouts)... Thanks for the tip :) No offence, I'll accept & close once my boss informs me whether he got any feedback on the support case :/ Time to go to bed now ;)

Comment: Probably unrelated, but na14 metadata API calls right now are so slow they're unusable. Nothing on trust.salesforce.com reflects this either. Funny, as I'm writing this it became usable again. But it's been on and off for a few hours now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you're not the only one having problems. Seems several people are asking about it on [twitter #askforce cs7](https://twitter.com/search?q=#askforce%20cs7&src=typd%20%27twitter%20#askforce%22).  The general advise from salesforce seems to be to contact support.

I did, and was told a higher R&D team is already investigating the problem.

The trust.salesforce.com status for cs7 has also been updated:

> 2:00 PM UTC: CS7 Performance Degradation
>   The salesforce.com Technology Team is working to isolate a performance degradation issue affecting Dashboard and Report refreshes on the CS7 instance. A small subset of customers may experience delays when using these features.
>
> Please check the status of trust.salesforce.com frequently for updates regarding this issue.

But doesn't mention the metadata api (deploys/eclipse/..)

**edit:** We've received an update on the case, issues on CS7 instance should be resolved. The trust.salesforce status has also been updated:

> Detail: The salesforce.com Technology Team has resolved the performance degradation issue affecting the MetaData API processes, including the Force.com Migration Toolkit on the CS7 instance. The problem began on November 30, 2012 at 12:45 UTC and was resolved by 18:00 UTC. During this time, a subset of customers may have experienced delays or errors while using these features. Thank you for your continued business and patience during this situation.
>
> Root Cause: The problem was caused by a long running background database process which blocked access to specific database resources. This process was stopped and the requests dependent on these resources were able to resume normal processing.
>
> Actions to Prevent Future Incidents:
>   The salesforce.com Technology Team -
>   - Has disabled the background process while we investigate its behavior 
>   - Is investigating improvements to better manage resource utilization and prevent future occurrences from causing customer impact

Comment: I've just had an updated email "The salesforce.com Technology Team continues to work on isolating the performance degradation issue effecting the MetaData API Processes, including the Force.com migration toolbox, on the CS7 instance."